# Joda-Time getMillisOfDay() seems to be advancing more rapidly than java.util.Date's getTime() milliseconds value

Tags: java, jodatime

I've just started using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) and I ran into something that looks quite strange.

When I sleep for 1 ms and call getMillisOfDay() before and after the sleep, Joda-Time is telling me that  119  milliseconds elapsed. Using java.util.Date (creating an instance before and after the sleep, and taking the difference of the getTime() value returned by each) reports a much smaller elapsed time value (2 milliseconds). which is longer than the 1 milliseconds  actual sleep time, but I'm guessing the object overhead of creating the Date had an impact, in any case the elapsed time reported for java.util.Date was far less than that reported by Joda-Time.)

Here is my little test method:

```java
@Test(enabled = true)
public void testsleep() {

    LocalDateTime now = new  LocalDateTime();
    System.out.println("jodatime before millisecs:" + now.getMillisOfDay());
    Thread.sleep(1);
    LocalDateTime now2 = new  LocalDateTime();
    System.out.println("jodatime  after millisecs:" + now2.getMillisOfDay());

    System.out.println("java.util.DATE before call:" + new Date().getTime());
    Thread.sleep(1);
    Date after = new Date();
    System.out.println("java.util.DATE after call:" + after.getTime());

    println "done"
}
```

**output:**

```
jodatime before millisecs:76672505
jodatime  after millisecs:76672624
java.util.DATE before call:1396671472633
java.util.DATE after call:1396671472635
```

**analysis:**

```
jodatime  after millisecs:76672624
jodatime before millisecs:76672505
                        ----------------
                    119 millisecs elapsed according to joda time

java.util.DATE  after call:1396671472635
java.util.DATE before call:1396671472633
                        ----------------
                    2 millisecs elapsed according to java util Date
```

I thought Joda-Time was better that java.util.Date. Well, I'm sure it is, and I’m just using it wrong. but I don’t see how. Any advice much appreciated !

Comment: No such class as `LocalDateTime` is Joda-Time. Did you mean `DateTime` or `LocalTime`? Please specify, as you have raised a curious issue.

Comment: @Basil: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html

Comment: Thanks Anthony. I stand corrected. [`LocalDateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html) `is an unmodifiable datetime class representing a datetime without a time zone.`

Comment: Not surprising: `new Date()` is much more light-weight than `new LocalDateTime()`, hence the difference. However, Anthonys alternative is really better for benchmarking.

Comment: FYI, take a look at the [Java Microbenchmark Harness (JMH)](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) tool. [JEP 230](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/230) proposes adding this to the OpenJDK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't use neither `Date` nor `LocalDateTime` for measuring short intervals of time. The main reason for this in written in your question, there is a considerable overhead for object creation (check out [LocalDateTime source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.3/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.java#LocalDateTime)). Also keep in mind that the JVM need some time to warm up (let JVM optimizations kick in and do its magic).

While you shouldn't benchmark like this (there are lot of good benchmark tools for Java), a good low level alternative is `System.nanoTime()`. `StopWatch` classes might also come in handy (like [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html), [Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/StopWatch.html) and [Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StopWatch.html) implementations).

Finally, remember that [Thread.sleep](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) is itself subject to precision problems.

```
// Run several times to *warm up*
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    double init = System.nanoTime();
    Thread.sleep(1);
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.printf("Elapsed time: %.2f milliseconds\n", (end - init) * 1e-6); 
}
```

Comment: OK, I'll buy that. Seems like Joda time guys should update their docs to warn that these classes should not be used for millisecond level precision operations.   I glanced at the source.. didn't see anything that looked glaringly high resource consuming that would contribute to 100 ms worth of processing.  I'd be interested to know what you think is the main culprit...  But that's just curiosity.... I know now not to rely on Joda time for low resolution tracking.   But actually java.util.Date did seem to give me accurate results.   Oh well.. Let's hope java 1.8 sorts all this out!  thanks! /cb

Comment: Actually I disagree, the problem is not Joda-Time precision, is the way that you have used the wrong tool (a partial) for the job (measuring duration). `Instant.now().getMillis()` will better serve the bill. Also, your benchmark is flawed, there is not 100 ms of processing after warm up, even with the broken `LocalDateTime.getMillisOfDay()` approach.

Comment: About JSR 310 (Date and Time) vs Joda-Time, I've wrote [my own flawed benchmark](https://gist.github.com/aaccioly/10002565) and run it using Java 8. Every measuring method was very precise, averaging near the 1 millisecond expected result. Even the broken `getMillisOfDay()` approach did ok after the initial warm up and averaged slightly above 1 millisecond (the first run took near 30ms; according to the Netbeans Profiler the expensive part was related to `ISOChronology.getInstance`). In conclusion: Be very, very careful about micro benchmarks.

Comment: [Java 9 brings a new implementation](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068730) of [`Clock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) to be capable of capturing current moment in up to nanosecond resolution. May help with benchmarking (I don't know; haven't tried it or looked at details yet).